# About UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Can I get the middle point coordinate of the UIRotationGestureRecognizer's two fingers? Or the location of each finger? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get either.

The docs for `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` show the properties `velocity` and `rotation`.

This is specific to the rotation.

But you can use these methods from the UIGestureRecognizer...

```
Getting the Touches and Location of a Gesture
– locationInView:
– locationOfTouch:inView:
– numberOfTouches
```

To get the touches and locations.

From these you can easily calculate the mid point.

Answer (score 1):

`UIRotationGestureRecognizer` extends `UIGestureRecognizer` which has the two methods: `numberOfTouches` and `locationOfTouch:inView:`. Use these to get the location of each finger. From there you can calculate a center.